# Populate ASP Table With Data Table Results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am filling a dataset with results from a sql server stored procedure.  I am then converting my data table  to a data table by simply using `dt = ds.Tables[0];`

Now that I have the data table populated how do I iterate the rows to fill a asp:table?

**EDIT** --
Essentially what I need is a way of displaying my data so that I can have a total row each time my selection changes.  Meaning, I am showing monthly turnover ratio for about 16 different stores, so the data would be similar to

```
Store....Turnover....Month<br>
1            0         1<br>
1            2         2<br>
1            3         3<br>
Total        5<br>
2            0         1<br>
2            1         2<br>
2            2         3<br>
Total        3<br>
```

Comment: You can use something like GridView control and set it's DataSource property to dt and call GridView.Bind()

Comment: @Harsh does a gridview have an tepeater property?

Comment: What do you mean by "an accumulator property"? Also check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx to see if any of the inbuilt data web controls will work for you.

Comment: @jon P I was confused in thinking the repeater was a property of a datagrid or dataview not its own entity in itself.  Thank you for that invaluable website.

Comment: Here's another handy article on how to keep a running total to use in the footer. You might be able to get some inspiration from that. Also keep track of the current store ID then you can insert a "total" row when the store ID changes. Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx